# Can not export HTML table data to excel sheet in chrome using Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, google-chrome

I could not export my HTML table data to Excel sheet using Chrome. It only happens while table has larger no of data but for small amount of data its working. Here is my code:

```
$scope.generateExcelSheet=function(){
     var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    var table='exportable';
    var name='Report';
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
}
```

This code is working for less no of rows present inside that table for 'chrome' but while large no of row data is there its not working. I do not know why this is happening like this. I need to export the data into Excel sheet.

Comment: It seems that chrome has a URL size limit of 2MB. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=69227. So if your `data:` URI is to big, it will fail. But this approach for exporting Excel is anyway not recommendable. There are better possibilities to do so. [DataTables](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html) for example.

Comment: try this using Blob and BlobURL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686430/excel-export-in-javascript-using-blob-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: Let me try these and let u know.

Comment: @OmasuPlus : I tried but the sheet is generating but its not coming in proper order.Check this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/BsZ0rXqjZKPwAhPGLAFp?p=preview).

Comment: Your `table1` variable as the HTML template lacks a `<table>` start tag. So instead  `...</head><body>"+table+"</table></body>...` set `...</head><body><table>"+table+"</table></body>...`. But as said, there are better possibilities to export Excel from HTML using Javasript.

Comment: @AxelRichter : Its exporting the blank file in my project.

Comment: This https://plnkr.co/edit/7SpjRRdryHOjO3nSVp9n?p=preview works for me using Chrome.

Comment: @AxelRichter : but its not working in safari.any solution for that.