# about:blank#blocked error when export table in excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

Javascript code table to excel data

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tableToExcel = (function () {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
      , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
      , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
      , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function (table, name,action) {

        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
    }
})();
</script>
```

Action Button

```
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Export" onclick="tableToExcel('tblConsolidate','Report','Fifth Batch')" />
```

table design

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tblConsolidate">
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>
   Head 1
 </th>
 <th>
   Head 2
 </th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody style="text-align:center;">
  <tr>
  <td>
    body 1
 </td>
   <td>
    body 2
 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
```

**Question**

when above ***table export  to excel*** function worked good for small data but when ***rows above 800 rows and columns almost 20 or more*** then it showed **about:blank#blocked** error and     export failed

what is the problem why this blocked and what should be change in my code ?

Comment: I face the same - anybody knows help?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, I solved it by saving it as a blob.

I believe the issue was caused by hitting the data URL data limit (2 mb on chrome?), by storing it as a blob increases your data limit by a lot (2 gigs?).

This answer was pretty helpful: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/36502388][1]

```html
var tableToExcel = (function () {

        var myBlob =  new Blob( [table.innerHTML] , {type:'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = "export.xls";
        a.click();
      //adding some delay in removing the dynamically created link solved the problem in FireFox
        setTimeout(function() {window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);},0);

});
//and call the function:
tableToExcel();
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your answer, consider editing to explain how/why key bits of your code solves the OP's issue.. Quality answers which help visitors learn something they can apply to their own coding are more likely to receive upvotes over time. Text also helps visitors quickly focus on key elements of your code.

Answer (score 1):

**I solved it using this code**

```
var tableToExcel = (function () {
  var encabezado = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" 
  content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/><style> table, td {border:thin solid 
  black} table {border-collapse:collapse}</style></head><body><table>';

  var dataTable = table.innerHTML
  var piePagina = "</table></body></html>";
  var tabla = encabezado + dataTable + piePagina;
  var myBlob =  new Blob( [tabla] , {type:'text/html'});
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.href = url;
  a.download = "export.xls";
  a.click();
  
  setTimeout(function() {window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);},0);
});
```

Comment: Maybe you could say what did you changed instead of just posting the code that worked for you ?